# Java wait until variable is set

Tags: java, user-interface

```
    Calibrate calibrate = new Calibrate();
    calibrate.run();
    dict = new HashMapStore().getDictionary();
```

Is there a way to wait until calibrate(a gui) is done running, then set dict.

edit:
I'm positive calibrate is on the same thread, however, if I print something at under the dict = new HashMapStore().getDictionary(), it prints immediately.

Comment: Does calibrate start a new thread or submit work to be done in another thread? If not, the `dict = ...` line won't be executed until `calibrate.run()` completes. (Or rather, the `dict = ...` line _always_ runs after `calibrate.run()` completes -- the only question is whether you can be sure that calibration is actually done at that point.)

Comment: What is a `Calibrate` exactly? Does it have a method you can call that returns a boolean indicating if it's done? Better yet, does it have a way to register an event listener that will receive an event indicating it's done?

Comment: Calibrate is just another class that runs a gui, same thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Calibrate is executed in same thread than your main program, then the execution is synchronous, I mean each sentence is executed sequentially, so you don't need to do nothing special.

On the other had, if Calibrete.run() is executed in other thread maybe you could consider use a FutureTask.get(), it will wait until process ends to continue with the execution.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html